# Hammerspoon Key Repeats

Tags: macos, lua, hammerspoon

I am so glad I found hammerspoon. I am having issues coming from windows to mac os. I have been using autohotkey in the past and have this script that I cannot live without while playing world of warcraft. I suffered a hand injury and can't play without the following script:

```
{
$r::
   Loop  
   {
    if not GetKeyState("r", "P")
      break
     Send r
     Sleep 40
    }
return
}
```

All it does is key repeat the letter r while holding it down. I use an addon in world of warcraft called gnomesequenceenhanced to put my abilities in to play. and the scritp uses the same button over and over until released to cast my abilities.

I would be forever greatful if you would be able to get this so I can upload and use this in the config and save the init.lua

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. Why is this tagged Lua? this is no Lua code

Comment: He's asking for the Hammerspoon Lua equivalent of this AutoHotKey code

Comment: im willing to pay a developer to get this to work